# How to update in MySQL: set website to www.website.com/"partnumber"

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am somewhat familiar with PHP coding, but right now I am using phpMyAdmin and have a problem with the most basic of things.

I would like to update the website links with a given `website` link + `partnumber`. `partnumber` is given in the same table. Something like this:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `website`="http://www.website.com/'".$partnumber."'" WHERE `website`="http://www.website.com";
```

This obviously does not work.

Comment: Where would $partnumber be coming from?

Comment: You're misunderstanding what phpmyadmin is. It's not a way to use php in sql commands, it's an administrative interface for mysql which was itself written in php.

If you want to update rows using SQL in phpmyadmin, you have to use pure SQL, you can't include PHP in your SQL the way you're trying to..

Comment: i dont know where it would come from or how i could reference it, thats why i added that it is in the same table. maybe that would help?!


@mrcheshire so you suggest i just make a php script like i normally would and run it and shouldnt bother with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  `products`
SET
  `website` = CONCAT('http://www.website.com/', `partNumber`)
WHERE
  `website` = 'http://www.website.com';
```

You are looking for the [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

As an alternative, you can use the following as well:

```
UPDATE
  `products`
SET
  `website` = CONCAT(`website`, '/', `partNumber`)
WHERE
  `website` = 'http://www.website.com';
```

As a bonus: If you want to be compatible to more possible MySQL configurations, use single quote for string literals rather than double quotes as this works with [ANSI quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) as well.